# IL (Intermediate Language) Code in Native .NET Images

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly

Consider a simple Console .NET app, that only contains the Visual Studio's auto-generated and empty Main method.

As per Jeffrey Richter's "CLR via C#" in the context of `mscorlib.dll`: "*This assembly is automatically loaded when the CLR initializes*". Quite understandable, given that this assembly contains - among others - the core types.

Running the application and setting a filter to look for "mscorlib" file references only yields hits both for `mscorlib.dll` as well as `mscorlib.ni.dll`:

[image]

The "ni" stands for native image, and given that the `mscorlib.dll` assembly is so heavily used, it makes sense to make a native image out of it - `mscorlib.ni.dll` -, which the CLR will load instead of the "classical", `mscorlib.dll` one.

The fact that both files are being accessed is expected, since the CLR will only use the native image as long as it's still in sync with the original assembly it was generated from. If for example the source assembly changes, the native image is [no longer used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator). Therefore both need to be checked before loading the native one. All clear so far.

The native images, as Microsoft states [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator), "*are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code*".

Assuming a native image *only* contains machine code, I went ahead and tried to open `mscorlib.ni.dll` with a disassembler ([ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy)), simply expecting the "PE file does not contain any managed metadata" error to be thrown. I was however surprised to see ILSpy correctly loading the assembly, complete with manifest, type members, as well as *IL code* displayed for methods:

[image]

I suspected that somehow a reference to `mscorlib.dll` is used, and the whole data is extracted from there actually. However Process Monitor filtered for ILSpy's image name proved me wrong: there's not even one attempt to open `mscorlib.dll`; there are only some attempts to get the .pdb file - most likely looking for symbols - that fail due to that file not existing.

In fact both assemblies - `mscorlib.dll` and `mscorlib.ni.dll` - are striking similar, with just the difference of IL_ONLY vs IL_LIBRARY in the Corflags structure.

Trying to load other native images from within the NIC (Native Image Cache) resulted in a similar behavior.

I could find advanced details about how a native image is still deemed valid ([here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2013/12/11/net-loading-native-ngen-images-and-its-interaction-with-the-gac/)), but no so much about my actual question:

**How come native images can be disassembled down to the IL code level ?** Is the IL as well as the machine code stored within the native image ?

*Update 5/27/2019*: It seems that Microsoft's definition is somewhat elusive. It should probably be interpreted as native images "*are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code*", ***aside the regular assembly metadata and IL code***. The "native" particle inside the term leads one to the wrong meaning apparently.

The 2 good comments received lead to the next natural question: **Where is the machine code actually stored inside the image file itself ?**

In terms of details about the image file content, [CFF Explorer](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=388) showed a bit more than JetBrain dotPeek, and highlighted 2 extra sections, a rather large Relocation Directory entry and a mysterious Native Header in favor of the native image, but that was pretty much it.

[image]

The ECMA 335 standard [enter link description here](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) has but a few words about the physical layout of the image file concerning the code itself in section II.25.4. Aside from the fact that the method body immediately follows the method header, and that there's sometimes an extra method data section when dealing with exception handling, the standard doesn't really tell anything about the location of the machine code itself.

Comment: That looks accurate, easiest way to implement it.  What is hard to see is the rather large amount of machine code that is embedded in the file.  Other than by the file size, 5.5 MB for mscorlib, 20 MB for mscorlib.ni.dll.  I don't know of any tool that can reveal it.

Comment: .NET have reflection. That means you should have managed metadata for it to work.

Comment: @HansPassant I've added what I could find, but just like you hinted, I haven't got myself very far.

Comment: @PetSerAl: You're absolutely right. Assuming the native images would contain nothing but native code, there wouldn't have been any bit of assembly metadata, let alone IL that could be retrieved by doing reflection. I didn't really connect the dots at the time.

Answer (score 0):

If no native image is available for a particular method, NGEN falls back to JITing code. This means that native images must continue to include metadata and IL in the event that NGEN needs to fall back to JIT compilation.